# Long startup of Ethernet connection in Win11

Tags: windows, ethernet, windows-11

For several weeks now, the ethernet connection of my miniPC (IT11) starts up very slow after boot or sleep (private home network). It takes almost a minute to get a connection. Wifi connection starts up fast, but I don't want 2 connections. The hardware hasn't changed, nor the settings. Yet, SW and/or driver updates might have occured. Switching from DHCP to manual settings of the ethernet adapter doesn't help.
[image: Ethernet configuration]

Comment: Do you have another network cable that you can use to try connecting directly to the router? Just to check it is not a wiring problem.

Comment: Agree with checking wiring.  Also do a TCP/IP reset and restart to test.

Comment: I haven't changed the cables. Same cabling as when everything was ok.

Comment: @monok Cables can go bad.